# How to merge two memory streams?

Tags: c#, .net, memorystream

I have two MemoryStream instances.

How to merge them into one instance?

Well, now I can't copy from one MemoryStream to another.
Here is a method:

```
public static Stream ZipFiles(IEnumerable<FileToZip> filesToZip) {
ZipStorer storer = null;
        MemoryStream result = null;
        try {
            MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream(1024);
            storer = ZipStorer.Create(memory, GetDateTimeInRuFormat());
            foreach (var currentFilePath in filesToZip) {
                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(currentFilePath.FullPath);
                storer.AddFile(ZipStorer.Compression.Deflate, currentFilePath.FullPath, fileName,
                               GetDateTimeInRuFormat());
            }
            result = new MemoryStream((int) storer.ZipFileStream.Length);
            storer.ZipFileStream.CopyTo(result); //Does not work! 
                                               //result's length will be zero
        }
        catch (Exception) {
        }
        finally {
            if (storer != null)
                storer.Close();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: What does "merge" mean?

Comment: This is *vague*. What are you trying to do? Code example?

Comment: Why is this downvoted?  This is very intuitive, -1 Robuust and -1 Jon.  An instance is when you allocate a class.  The object in question is a memory stream (which is a seekable array of bytes, like a file in memory).  Putting two files inside an archive file (zip) make sense.  Combining the bits of two files into what looks like one and then having the ability to split them apart is easy to understand.  Those are your only options.  p.s. give the guy a little to update their answer if it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Spectacularly easy with [CopyTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782932.aspx) or [CopyToAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782932.aspx):

```
var streamOne = new MemoryStream();
FillThisStreamUp(streamOne);
var streamTwo = new MemoryStream();
DoSomethingToThisStreamLol(streamTwo);
streamTwo.CopyTo(streamOne); // streamOne holds the contents of both
```

The framework, people.  The *framework*.

Comment: Make sure you adjust the positions for the Copy operation, StreamOne position must equal its length and StreamTwo position must be 0.

Comment: Can streamTwo clone/copy be avoided, to increase performance?

Comment: Of course. Write an implementation of Stream that outputs the contents of two or more child streams.

Answer (score 5):

Based on the answer shared by @Will above, here is complete code:

```
void Main()
{
    var s1 = GetStreamFromString("Hello");
    var s2 = GetStreamFromString(" World");

    var s3 = s1.Append(s2);
    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString((s3 as MemoryStream).ToArray()));
}

public static Stream GetStreamFromString(string text)
{
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
        writer.Write(text);
        writer.Flush();
        stream.Position = 0;

        return stream;
}

public static class Extensions
{ 
    public static Stream Append(this Stream destination, Stream source)
    {
        destination.Position = destination.Length;
        source.CopyTo(destination);

        return destination;
    }
}
```

And merging stream collection with `async`:

```
async Task Main()
{
    var list = new List<Task<Stream>> { GetStreamFromStringAsync("Hello"), GetStreamFromStringAsync(" World") };

    Stream stream = await list
            .Select(async item => await item)
            .Aggregate((current, next) => Task.FromResult(current.Result.Append(next.Result)));

    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString((stream as MemoryStream).ToArray()));
}

public static Task<Stream> GetStreamFromStringAsync(string text)
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
    writer.Write(text);
    writer.Flush();
    stream.Position = 0;

    return Task.FromResult(stream as Stream);
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static Stream Append(this Stream destination, Stream source)
    {
        destination.Position = destination.Length;
        source.CopyTo(destination);

        return destination;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

- Create third(let it be `mergedStream`) `MemoryStream` with length
  equal to sum of first and second lengths
- Write first `MemoryStream` to `mergedStream` (use [`GetBuffer()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.getbuffer.aspx) to
  get `byte[]` from `MemoryStream`)
- Write second `MemoryStream` to `mergedStream`(use [`GetBuffer()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.getbuffer.aspx))
- Remember about offset while writing.

It's rather ***append***, but it's totally unclear what is merge operation on MemoryStreams