# How to Merge PDFs From a ZipArchive in to one PDF in Memory

Tags: c#, .net-core, itext, itext7, c#-ziparchive

I have an application that needs to read Zip files that contain a full directory and multiple files.

[image]

I have it working to read each pdf and write it to disk then combine afterwards.  However, the I/O is dumb.  I want to read each pdf from the zip file and combine in to one in one method.

I could only find [this example that uses iTextSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32204310/how-to-merge-two-memory-streams-containing-pdf-files-data-into-one) which is deprecated.

Here is what I have so far:

```
public static void ProcessZipFileTest(string zipFile)
{
    List<string> pdfFiles = new List<string>();

    try
    {
        MemoryStream finalStream = new MemoryStream();

        using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(zipFile))
        {
            foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
            {
                if (entry.FullName.EndsWith(".pdf", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    //// Write the file to disk for combining separately
                    //string destinationPath = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(ProcessingFolder, Path.GetFileName(entry.FullName)));
                    //entry.ExtractToFile(destinationPath);
                    //pdfFiles.Add(destinationPath);

                    PdfCopyFields copy = new PdfCopyFields(finalStream);    // this is the iTextSharp way and outdated
                    string file1Path = "Sample1.pdf";
                    string file2Path = "Sample2.pdf";

                    var ms1 = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(file1Path));
                    ms1.Position = 0;
                    copy.AddDocument(new PdfReader(ms1));
                    ms1.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }

        // write the final stream to disk
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // TODO LOG FAILURE
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @KJ.  Could you provide an example of this?

Comment: You're gonna need to use something like PDFSharp if you actually want one pdf that's a combination of multiple PDFs. It's not a perfect tool but it works for 99.9+% of PDFs out there. Is that something you've looked at?

Comment: @EmperorEto *"You're gonna need to use something like PDFSharp if you actually want one pdf that's a combination of multiple PDFs."* - The OP has found a solution with iTextSharp and is looking for a solution with iText 7. Both are multi-purpose PDF libraries. Thus, the OP already has _something like PDFSharp_...

Comment: FatherOfDiwaffe - So you found the iTextSharp example. If you have tested it and it works for you (except being deprecated), then you can create an equivalent, not deprecated solution with iText 7 or 8. If you have not tested it, you should do so because of the memory constraints @KJ mentioned.

Comment: @mlk yes and they also pointed out that iTextSharp is deprecated and appeared to want a different solution. I also wasn't sure if they were looking to just combine the bytes and somehow get a working PDF file, which will not work. I know from personal experience that PDFSharp will work in this instance, and operates under a permissive FOSS license unlike iText, so that's my recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

Based on feedback, I'm going to write to disk and combine.  The speed will be tested.