# How can i append new csv data in existing file in block blob type storage in dotnet core.I have tried to append but it is showing error

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-blob-storage

**Here is my code:**

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(AzureWebJobsStorage);
CloudBlobClient serviceClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer container = serviceClient.GetContainerReference(ContainerName); 
// CloudBlobContainer containerbackup = serviceClient.GetContainerReference(ContainerNameBackup); 
CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(FileName);
// CloudBlockBlob blobBackUp = containerbackup.GetBlockBlobReference(FileName);
// CloudAppendBlob appendBlob = container.GetAppendBlobReference(FileName);
byte[] csvFile = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(csveventcontent.ToString().Trim());

if ( await blob.ExistsAsync())

    using (var appendFileStream = new MemoryStream(csvFile))
    await blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(appendFileStream);

else
{
    using (var uploadFileStream = new MemoryStream(csvFile))
    {
    await blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(uploadFileStream);
    uploadFileStream.Close();

    }  
}
```

Comment: *but it is showing error* - if you got an error, why don't you show it in your question? Error messages are usually quite important information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no method to append data directly. [`UploadFromStreamAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.uploadfromstreamasync?view=azure-dotnet-legacy) is used to upload a stream to a block blob. If the blob already exists, it will be overwritten.

You could download the blob file as stream, then append the stream of csv data, and upload the new stream finally.

```
// download the blob stream:
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
await blob.DownloadToStreamAsync(stream);    
stream.Position = 0;

// append the stream, refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15655210/how-to-merge-two-memory-streams
var newStream = Append(stream, appendFileStream);

// upload the new stream
await blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(newStream);
```

---

Append stream method:

```
public static Stream Append(Stream destination, Stream source)
{
    destination.Position = destination.Length;
    source.CopyTo(destination);
    destination.Position = 0;
    return destination;
}
```

---

**My test code:**

```
class Program
{
    static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var StorageConnectionString = "";

        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(StorageConnectionString);
        CloudBlobClient serviceClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer container = serviceClient.GetContainerReference("pamelac");
        CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("test.txt");

        var appendFileStream = GetStreamFromString("hello"); // just for test, it will be "var appendFileStream = new MemoryStream(csvFile);" in your case

        // download the blob stream:
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        await blob.DownloadToStreamAsync(stream);
        stream.Position = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("download stream to string: \n" + Encoding.UTF8.GetString((stream as MemoryStream).ToArray()));

        // append the stream
        var newStream = Append(stream, appendFileStream);
        Console.WriteLine("new stream to string: \n" + Encoding.UTF8.GetString((newStream as MemoryStream).ToArray()));

        // upload the new stream
        await blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(newStream);

    }

    public static Stream GetStreamFromString(string text)
    {
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
        writer.Write(text);
        writer.Flush();
        stream.Position = 0;

        return stream;
    }
    public static Stream Append(Stream destination, Stream source)
    {
        destination.Position = destination.Length;
        source.CopyTo(destination);
        destination.Position = 0;
        return destination;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: copyToAsync is not adding 2 stream..i have tried but its is not appending

Comment: Plz try my update method, it works well. https://i.stack.imgur.com/X83Bv.png

Comment: Make sure you adjust the positions for the Copy operation, `destination` position must equal its length and `source` position must be 0.

Comment: //Getting error with append
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
                 await blob.DownloadToStreamAsync(stream); 
                 stream.Position = 0;
                 byte[] blobstream = stream.ToArray();
                 
                var existStream = GetStreamFromString(blobstream.ToString());
                var newStream = GetStreamFromString(csvFile.ToString());

                var appendstream = existStream.Append(newStream);

Comment: m getting output as System.IO.MemoryStream in  existing file.

Comment: I just use GetStreamFromString as an example(I append the two string in my local), you don't need to use it. There are 2 streams in your issue, the downloaded one and the appended one, and you could append them using `Append(stream, appendFileStream)`

Comment: Add all my test code in the reply. If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer, thank you.

Comment: //Thanks for help but still my csv file is not appending.
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
                        await blob.DownloadToStreamAsync(stream);
                        stream.Position = 0;
                        using (var newFileStream = new MemoryStream(csvFile))
                        {
                            stream.Append (newFileStream);
                            await blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(stream);  
                            stream.Close();
                            newFileStream.Close();

Comment: my memory stream length is increasing when m appending but in file it is showing 0 b.

Comment: Could you edit your issue to share your code?

Comment: It's important to set the `newStream.Position = 0;`. If not, you will upload an empty file.

Comment: //Not able to post my full code//
 MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
                        await blob.DownloadToStreamAsync(stream);
                        stream.Position = 0;
                        using (var newFileStream = new MemoryStream(csvFile))
                        {
                          newFileStream.Position = 0;
                            stream.Append (newFileStream);
                            await blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(stream);
                            stream.Close();
                            newFileStream.Close();

Comment: I mean the stream uploaded at the end need to set the position: `var newStream = Append(stream, appendFileStream);
        newStream.Position = 0;` .

Comment: yes i set the position 0 for both the stream.However my stream length and capacity  is increasing when m debugging but in file it is showing 0 bytes.

Comment: You just set the newFileStream, it's not what I mentioned. Maybe set `destination.Position = 0;` in the Append method will help you understand.

Comment: thankyou so much ...i got your point and now it is working.sorry for all the inconvenience to you.

Comment: If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer(click on the mark option beside the reply to toggle it from greyed out to fill in.), see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work